# How can I concatenate 2 or more 3 data columns in asp.net before binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datatable

I have the following datatable.

```
clientcode   - jobcode - sitename
abc          bcd         http://ourlocaldomain.com/sites/
```

I need a new column where value should be instead: http://ourlocaldomain.com.sites/abc/bcd

The code I have is as follows:

```
  var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);
            keywordQuery.SortList.Add("Modified", SortDirection.Descending);

            var dataTable = KQLUtilities.ExecuteKql(keywordQuery, queryText, selectedProperties.ToArray(), keywordQuery.SortList);

            var jobSiteUrl = new DataColumn("JobSiteUrl");
            jobSiteUrl.Expression = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", "SiteName", "ClientCode", "JobCode");

            dataTable.Columns.Add(jobSiteUrl);
```

The error I have is:

```
Cannot find column [ClientCodeJobCode].
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a calculated column in your DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have assigned the expression right now, the expression will be:

```
SiteName/ClientCodeJobCode
```

So when evaluating the expression, the code will try to take the value in the `SiteName` column and divide it with the value in the `ClientCodeJobCode` column.

As per MSDN (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)), string concatenation in expressions are done using the `+` operator.

Based on your exact sample data, this should give you the output you want:

```
jobSiteUrl.Expression = "SiteName + ClientCode + '/' + JobCode";
```

Output would be:

```
http://ourlocaldomain.com/sites/abc/bcd
```

This differs from your sample url (=`http://ourlocaldomain.com.sites/abc/bcd`) , but I believe that you have a typo there. The `.` before `sites` should probably be a `/`, right?

If in some cases your site name will not include a trailing `/` you could use this expression which will check if the dash is there and add it in case it's needed:

```
jobSiteUrl.Expression = "SiteName + IIF(SUBSTRING(SiteName, LEN(SiteName), 1) = '/', '', '/') + ClientCode + '/' + JobCode";
```

Comment: Yes I had a typo there,  your code in the comment before worked perfectly!